# What is the web URL to replace an HP drive? (no phone / chat)

Tags: hp

I have a failed HP drive and would like to replace it using HP's web form (online) process.

Does anyone know what that URL is? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is hard to find, just like a lot of things on the HP web-site. The method I use to get there:

1. Log in to the [Business Support Center](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Home.jsp).
2. Click "Edit your profile".
3. Click "View or modify my support cases".

That gets me to one spot to do it. There may be others. They do tend to change things around and not fix dead links.